# Skype response language parameter

Tags: botframework, skype, skypedeveloper

While sending request to bot through web Skype, it is sending locale as 'en-US'. How I can change it to any other language? How Skype decide automatically to send it to 'en-US'?

'entities': [{'locale': 'en-US', 'country': 'US', 'platform': 'Web', 'type': 'clientInfo'}]

Comment: Are you using .Net SDK?

Comment: No I am using Microsoft bot python SDK.

Comment: I added the tag [botframework-v4] as it is Python's SDK

Comment: I believe this gets set inside of the client's settings itself, so it depends on which client you're using. Are you using the Skype WebChat or something like Skype for Windows? Which version are you using?

Comment: @StevenG. I am using Skype for windows .! my question is why it is showing locale as 'en-US' when I am sending request in Russian language?

Comment: @NicolasR But my question is nowhere related to botframework. It is totally related to Skype.

Comment: It is linked. It is a bot connector vs channel question

Comment: @NicolasR Sorry if you misunderstood my question. I am asking why "Skype" shows locale as 'en-US' in its response when I am sending text in Russian language?

Comment: I totally understand your question, no worry. But that's linked to bot framework

Comment: @NicolasR many thanks ! So If you understood my question, can u help me finding its answer?

Comment: I added an answer below

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks for the support. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible answer

I don't have access to the Bot Connector sources so it will be difficult to ensure that my answer is valid, but I think your language value comes from one of the following properties:

- Language of your Skype profile
- Language of the installed Skype app you are using
- Language of the operating system where you use Skype

### Why I am assuming it is one of those values?

You can have a look how it is made on other channels, in particular if you have a look to the open-source Webchat channel, you will see the following [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Chat.tsx#L65) :

```
locale: props.locale || (window.navigator as any)["userLanguage"] || window.navigator.language || 'en'
```

So in the Webchat, it is using (in order of priority):

- the locale set in webchat properties (coming from the queryString for example)
- the "userLanguage" of the navigator if any
- the navigator language if any
- `en` as default value

Comment: Building off of this Bot Framework does not interpret user requests to set the locale; I would also expect that Skype does not do this either. As Nicolas mentioned and I indicated in a comment on the question, it's most likely set by the client when the request is generated. You should try changing the Skype [settings](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA73/how-do-i-change-the-language-used-by-skype-for-windows-desktop) and seeing if the locale is changed when the activity hits your bot.

Comment: To set the locale in the bot, you can prompt the user to pick their locale and store that locale in the User databag; here are two examples: [Node.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-localization/app.js) and [C#](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ChooseLanguageBot)

Comment: @StevenG. I think Skype doesn't gave option to set locale on our own. As Nicolas suggested may be its because of skype profile or OS language. I need to check and will update you guys. 
Thanks for your support !!