# What all languages Skype channel support for Bot?

Tags: botframework, bots, skype

I am using **Skype channel** for my **Bot**. As I am moving towards multi-lingual bot, 
I've a query - what all locale **Skype channel** support for **Bot user**?

For ex. When I send some message using Skype in any language, it always show locale in response as 'en-US' but not the corresponding locale.

Comment: Can you details what you mean by "what all language Skype channel support for Bot user?" : are you talking about the Locale field provided on the messages, about the supported languages on display (like special characters in some languages), or even something else?

Comment: @NicolasR Yes, I am talking about the Locale field provided on the messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skype response language parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481060/skype-response-language-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find the language supported by Skype [Language supported in Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34762/what-languages-are-supported-in-skype)

Since a chatbot behaves like an individual user in a channel so the bot can converse in the language that is supported by Skype

Comment: :: Thanks but I am talking about locale field provided on the messages. For ex. When you send some message in Russian language on Skype, in the response it will show you locale as 'en-US' but not Russian.

Comment: In that case you may use Microsft cognitive services like [Translator API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) this service automatically detect languagea. Or you may take a look on these approach [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: You may in the Locale field one of the values in the document provided by Harsh Raj. You have to understand that Skype will not detect the language of the user for you, it is using a parameter (maybe from the user profile, or skype app installation language)

Comment: @NicolasR Correct, skype detects the language from the user preference so Himanshu will have to use some mediator to detect the language at first place.

Comment: @NicolasR Actually I am using Google Dialogflow for NLU and dialog management. And if you've worked on Dialogflow you'll get better understanding that it needs language parameter to send response in that particular language.

Comment: Yes, but that was not your question, and if you post a precise question you will get help towards your problematic. As @HarshRaj said there are tools to get the real language used, that may be what you are looking for but that's not what you asked for...

Comment: @NicolasR Sorry but the option Harsh Raj specified of translating text into particular language is not accurate and it will not work correctly in many cases. I think my question was simple - if Skype supports multiple locale or not?

Comment: And again our response is clear: Skype support many languages but it is not "detecting" the user language. The Locale value that you will get is the one from Skype parameters, it may not be the language used in the messages

Comment: Simple example: my Skype says language is French even when I am writing in English